# Type Error: Name has to refer to a struct enum or contract

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, remix

> Solidity: Type Error: Name has to refer to a struct enum or contract.

I am using Solidity language on Remix IDE.

```
contract MyContract {
    enum State {waiting, Ready, Active }
    state public state;

    constructor () public {
        state = State.Active; 
    }
function activate () public {
    state = State.Active;
}
function active ()
    public view returns (bool) {
        return state == State.Active;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

`state public state;`

The `state` must be upper case as it's the name of enum.

`State public state;`